# how to use @ExceptionHandler for different response types

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

We have 2 sets of controllers.. One response for returning HttpEntity(for ajax calls) and one for ModelAndView. All the controllers extend a BaseController and in which we have defined Exception Handling.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(final Exception e) {
  return new ResponseEntity<String>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

But this controller is only handling exceptions for controllers related to responding 'HttpEntity' but not ModelAndView. In this case do I need two base controllers to handle exceptions or can I modify this existing BaseController to handle all exceptions?

Comment: Have you tried adding another exception handler that returns a ModelAndView?

Comment: Tried that but no luck. Usually it enters the first function which matches the input parameters.

Comment: Taking what @Arahant said, one thing you might want to consider is pushing the error handling into your controller implementations, but moving the body of the actual method into an error handling service class, so you can maintain the code in one spot.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a separate handleException method for each controller.

You should put only common code in your BaseController, but the exception handlers are obviously not common as they have different logic.

Comment: I think what he is trying to accomplish is to have a common error handling proceedure for all controllers.  If he pushes the error handling into the controller, then he is maintaining multiple copies of the same error handling proceedures.